# Changes made in WP_Elementor but not published in live site

Tags: wordpress, caching, elementor

I have made a small text change on one of my wordpress website using elementor 3 but is not able to publish on live site. Solutions that I have tried so far but unsuccessful.

- Clear Browser cache, WP plugin cache and purge website server cache.
- Made changes again and view in incognito mode
- Change Elementor CSS Print Method to Internal Embedding
- Regenerate CSS and data in Elementor tools settings

Note: The only way I see change made is by adding `?` (querymode) to the url, but not without that.

Comment: Could you specify what cache plugin you are using?

Comment: I also looked that I was not using any cache plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The issue we were having was due to old hosting, since the DNS was pointing to old host, the changes made was reflecting in old WP admin but not in new one

All we have to do is point the DNS to new host. That resolved a problem .